# how to detect touch area in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i want to count the touches.but when i touch that image that has to be cover some area then only count will be increse.plese help me

```
function pop(event)

  if event.phase=="began" then

  elseif event.phase == "ended" then

    numValue=numValue+1
    print("tapcount value"..numValue)
    count.text=numValue
  end
end
lips:addEventListener("touch",pop)
```

Comment: plz give some suggestion.its possible or not

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to count the taps or the touches? If it's taps, which is what it looks like, take a look at this tutorial for doing just that: http://corona.techority.com/2012/07/30/how-to-use-double-tap-in-your-corona-app/ I know the title says "double tap" but it will work for any kind of tap counting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are looking for..?

```
local obj_1 = .....   ; obj.tag  = 1
local lips  = .....   ; lips.tag = 2
local count = .....

local numValue = 0
local clickedObj_tag = 0

    local function pop(e)
       if(clickedObj_tag~=e.target.tag)then
       clickedObj_tag = e.target.tag
       -- cover/highlight your object
    else
       numValue=numValue+1
       print("tapcount value"..numValue)
       count.text=numValue
       -- do rest of your code 
    end
    lips:addEventListener("touch",pop)
    obj_1:addEventListener("touch",pop)
```